# How to delete a nested object in chrome.storage.local storage in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

chrome.storage.local returns an Object and inside it you store data in the form of key-value pair using `chrome.storage.local.set({ key : 'value'})`,  which returns an object `{ key : value}` using `chrome.storage.local.get(key)`. I want to delete a data (**ok**) which is stored as `{ storedGroupsData : {ok : [], bye : []} }`

Comment: It's simply an object, so you would read it, delete the property, write the object again.